# DBIx::Class error "Can't find source for XXX"

Tags: perl, fixtures, dbix-class

When I try to dump database with [Fixtures](http://search.cpan.org/~skaufman/DBIx-Class-Fixtures-1.001036/lib/DBIx/Class/Fixtures.pm):

```
dbic-migration --schema_class App::Schema --database PostgreSQL -Ilib dump_all_sets
```

I got error:

```
DBIx::Class::Schema::source(): Can't find source for Schet at /home/xxx/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux/Moose/Meta/Method/Delegation.pm line 110
```

In main application I have no problem to write:

```
$schema->resultset('Schet')
```

How to fix this error and dump data into fixtures?

Comment: Could be a pluralization problem. DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader (and probably the other things for automatic data dumping) generate Result/table names based on rules for turning words into singular and plural. You often see an `s` in the end. Sometimes it's even smarter, and DBIC includes a load of modules as dependencies for various languages to make plural monikers for things. But if your tables are in a language it doesn't support (like German or probably Russian, especially if it's transliterated) it might fail. Maybe the DCSL and Fixtures created different names?

Comment: @simbabque: I have found [this](http://search.cpan.org/~ilmari/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader/Base.pm#naming). Today I am planning to experiment with that.

Comment: I got the same error when I used a lower-case tablename whereas it was declared with 1st letter capital. With MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

in the [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](https://metacpan.org/source/ILMARI/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader-0.07047/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader.pm#L535) we are connecting to the temporary schema.

When connection occur the schema is [cloned](https://metacpan.org/source/RIBASUSHI/DBIx-Class-0.082840/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema.pm#L524)

But because of there only [schema name is passed](https://metacpan.org/source/JJNAPIORK/DBIx-Class-Migration-0.058/lib/DBIx/Class/Migration/SchemaLoader.pm) nothing is [cloned](https://metacpan.org/source/RIBASUSHI/DBIx-Class-0.082840/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema.pm#L1008) and, as result, has empty class mapping. Which is wrong.

If you look carefully you will see that cloning occur twice: [here](https://metacpan.org/source/JJNAPIORK/DBIx-Class-Migration-0.001/lib/DBIx/Class/Migration/SchemaLoader.pm#L18) and [here](https://metacpan.org/source/RIBASUSHI/DBIx-Class-0.082840/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema.pm#L524). This extra cloning is wasteful and should be refactored.

As work around [here](https://metacpan.org/source/JJNAPIORK/DBIx-Class-Migration-0.058/lib/DBIx/Class/Migration/SchemaLoader.pm) should be passed reblessed into required namespace cloned schema:

```
sub _make_schema_at {
  my ($self, $name, %extra_opts) = @_;
  my $schema = $self->schema->clone;
  bless $schema, $name;
  DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::make_schema_at
    $schema, {_merge_opts(%extra_opts)}, [{_rearrange_connect_info($schema->storage)}];
}
```

**UPD**

[Lately](https://metacpan.org/source/ILMARI/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader-0.07047/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader.pm#L311), when new loader is created, the `naming` is forced to `current` instead of passed argument, which, in its turn, is cloned from application schema. (I do not check that, but when application will have its own [`naming`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::Base#naming), this will cause problems when dumping data) and [loader is invoked again](https://metacpan.org/source/ILMARI/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader-0.07047/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader.pm#L366). Here loader loads classes [based on table names](https://metacpan.org/source/ILMARI/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader-0.07047/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader/Base.pm#L1735) instead of package names( how it is done at `__PACKAGE__->load_namespaces( ... )` )

Finally `@to_register` lists differ:

[Here](https://metacpan.org/source/ILMARI/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader-0.07047/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader/Base.pm#L1898)

```
[
  Ip,
  App::Schema0::Result::Ip,
]
[
  Scheta,
  App::Schema0::Result::Scheta,
]
```

[Here](https://metacpan.org/source/RIBASUSHI/DBIx-Class-0.082840/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema.pm#L396):

```
[
  IP,
  App::Schema::Result::IP,
],
[
  Schet,
  App::Schema::Result::Schet,
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this recently, within a docker container.  Curiously, some DBIx directories had the wrong permissions on them.  They need to at least be readable.  Also check file/directory ownership.

Answer (score 0):

Like @bliako above, I ran into this error (albeit intermittently) when the DBIx::Class source was named with a capital letter, e.g. "Foo" with a table all lower, e.g. "foo"

Once I renamed the table, error so far has gone away.  In 10+ yrs of using this module I had never seen this before.